# Phone call between Desktop app using Twilio in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, twilio

I have acquired a Twilio phone number. Now my main objective is to enable voice call from and to my Desktop app made with Unity.

I am using the below code to make a phone call from my Twilio number to another number on my mobile phone.

```
private void Start()
{
   TwilioClient.Init(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
   var to = new PhoneNumber("+9185********");
   var from = new PhoneNumber("+120********");
   var call = CallResource.Create(
      twiml: new Twiml(CreateVoiceResponse()),
      to: to,
      from: from);
   Debug.Log(call.Sid);
}

private string CreateVoiceResponse()
{
   var response = new VoiceResponse();
   var start = new Start();
   start.Stream(name: "Example Audio Stream", url: "wss://mystream.ngrok.io/audiostream");
   response.Append(start);
   response.Say("I will sltream the next 30 seconds of audio through your websocket").Pause(60);
   return response.ToString();
}
```

How do I make a phone call from my Twilio number from one instance of the app to same Twilio number on another instance of the app?

I have seen the TwilioDevice API and Capability token solution, but that's only available for Java-Script. Any solution for C#?

Comment: An API should be accessible from any language. A client library makes it easier though. Does this help: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-make-outbound-phone-calls-csharp?